# Sunspot.index(Model.all) doesn't re-index, though bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex does

Tags: solr, mongoid, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am using the following gems:

```
sunspot_mongo (1.2.1)
sunspot_solr (2.2.3)
```

I am not re-indexing with callbacks after creation, because I am bulk inserting objects with [db.collection.insert()](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/method/db.collection.insert).

Instead I want to re-index products a few times per day, e.g. in a recurring Sidekiq job.

According to the [sunspot_solr README](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#reindexing-objects) I can run:

```
Sunspot.index(Model.all)
```

According to the logs, this does set a re-indexing in motion:

```
SOLR Request (2.7ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
SOLR Request (9.7ms)  [ path=update parameters={} ]
...
```

but it does not seem to result in anything becoming searchable. Any idea why this is?

Fyi, I can run this rake task with a successfull result:

```
bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex
```

but I can't put that one into a Sidekiq job.

For the record, this is how my Model looks like:

```
class Model
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Sunspot::Mongo

  searchable auto_index: false do
    string  :_id,          :stored => true
    text    :name,         :stored => true
  end
end
```